# How to add "href" with XmlWriter in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

I would like to add following line to my xlm-file with the XmlWriter in C#:

```
 <image href="c:\temp\test.png"/>
```

The WriteElementString does not work unfortunately - has anyone a solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it is an Attribute. Try [XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writeattributestring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Selman22 Isn't that the answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @Selman22 How would it looks like when using XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XmlWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter?view=netframework-4.7.2)...

```
using (XmlWriter w = Xmlwriter.Create("test.png"))
{
    w.WriteStartElement("image");
    w.WriteAttributeString("href", "c:\temp\test.png");
    w.WriteEndElement();
}
```

Remember the namespace: `System.Xml`